# text-align always return left by jQuery in IE

Tags: jquery, css, alignment

Not sure why text-align property always return left in jQuery for IE?

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       alert($('#ctl00').css('text-align'))
    });
</script>

<span style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" id="ctl00">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this fixed the problem:

```
textAlignProp = $(this).css('textAlign');
```

using textAlign instead of text-align.

Comment: That sounds really wierd. Works both for me in IE7 and 8. Are you sure you quoted `text-align` correctly in your first approach?

Comment: yes positive - alert($('#ctl00').css('text-align'))

also using latest version of jQuery (1.4.2)

Comment: so, textAlign returns consistent results for me for both IE and FF. Like what Peter suggested also, trying to get a div css by jQuery will not pose a problem.

Answer (score 2):

text-align won't work reliably inside a span, because it's not a block-level element.  Test it out inside a div, and I think you'll find the results more predictable.

Comment: yes you are right too! but I can't change the span to div for this instance, w/o making other major changes... so going for the js solution of textAlign.